# Using Flask-Sijax's Comet with Nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, sijax

I have a Flask app in which I'm using Sijax's Comet to stream data from the back end to the front end. This works normally when I'm running my app by starting it with the command `python app.py`

Now I'm trying to run my app with Nginx. Instead of streaming my data nicely as it comes along, the app seems to wait until all data has been streamed before sending it to the browser.

Is there some Nginx configuration or Sijax setting to enable or disable?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a nginx configuration like this on StackOverflow.

```
    proxy_buffering    off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;        
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_cache off;
```